# Ajax requests were working for me a few hours ago and now they're not

Tags: node.js, ajax, spotify

I've been building an application working with the spotify api, and I had it working a few hours ago, and now with no change to the code they're not working. I even checked-out previous commits where I knew it worked and it didn't work then either. Now if I console log the body of the ajax request from my node js server I receive this very weird looking html code, bearing in mind if it's an error with the spotify api it outputs some healthy looking error message in a JSON object:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang=en>
  <meta charset=utf-8>
  <meta name=viewport content="initial-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width">
  <title>Error 400 (Bad Request)!!1</title>
  <style>
    *{margin:0;padding:0}html,code{font:15px/22px arial,sans-serif}html{background:#fff;color:#222;padding:15px}body{margin:7% auto 0;max-width:390px;min-height:180px;padding:30px 0 15px}* > body{background:url(//www.google.com/images/errors/robot.png) 100% 5px no-repeat;padding-right:205px}p{margin:11px 0 22px;overflow:hidden}ins{color:#777;text-decoration:none}a img{border:0}@media screen and (max-width:772px){body{background:none;margin-top:0;max-width:none;padding-right:0}}#logo{background:url(//www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/1x/googlelogo_color_150x54dp.png) no-repeat;margin-left:-5px}@media only screen and (min-resolution:192dpi){#logo{background:url(//www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_150x54dp.png) no-repeat 0% 0%/100% 100%;-moz-border-image:url(//www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_150x54dp.png) 0}}@media only screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:2){#logo{background:url(//www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_150x54dp.png) no-repeat;-webkit-background-size:100% 100%}}#logo{display:inline-block;height:54px;width:150px}
  </style>
  <a href=//www.google.com/><span id=logo aria-label=Google></span></a>
  <p><b>400.</b> <ins>That’s an error.</ins>
  <p>Your client has issued a malformed or illegal request.  <ins>That’s all we know.</ins>
```

I'm really not clear on what's happened and I've even reset my secret with spotify and nothings changed, if I log the error code it returns 'null'. This code for this page looks like a phishing page anyway (note the "!!1" as well as the random link to google) so I have no idea what's going on.

Comment: Are you sure you're making the request to the right URL? The "That's all we know." message is one I see when using Google services - AFAIK Spotify is not a Google service.

Comment: Yeah they definitely are, like I said, it was working only a few hours ago, I've not touched the code since